# Reusing UITableViewCell in Multiple Sections

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In following code the **UILabel** text gets repeated for other rows. I know its a problem with table reusability, but cant figure out how to solve it. Everything looks fine even the counts that are being returned.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell;

//Doc Name
if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
    cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell= [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"]autorelease];

    }

    cell.textLabel.text= docName;
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:17.f];

    UILabel *name = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    name.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    name.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    name.frame = CGRectMake(600,2.0f,250,50);
    name.text = @"11:12:01";
    [cell addSubview:name];

}

//Joint Work
if(indexPath.section == 1)
{
    cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell= [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"]autorelease];

    }

    cell.textLabel.text= [jointWrkNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:17.f];
}

//Detailing
if(indexPath.section == 2)
{
    cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell= [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"]autorelease];

    }

    cell.textLabel.text= @"Detailing";
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:17.f];
}
}
```

Comment: Use different cell identifiers for the different if statements, otherwise the same cell is dequeued, and reused. It's pretty basic.

Comment: I don't see where you return the cell. I'd be surprised if this worked at all.

Comment: i am returning cell. it didnt come when i copied it.

Comment: Be sure to update your question with the correct code.

Comment: chk this http://iosdeveloperfamily.webs.com/apps/blog/show/24894137-label-overlap-each-other-when-scrolling-uitableview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell;

//Doc Name
if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
    cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"section_0_cell"];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell= [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"section_0_cell"]autorelease];

    }

    cell.textLabel.text= docName;
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:17.f];

    UILabel *name = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    name.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    name.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    name.frame = CGRectMake(600,2.0f,250,50);
    name.text = @"11:12:01";
    [cell addSubview:name];

}

//Joint Work
if(indexPath.section == 1)
{
    cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"section_1_cell"];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell= [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"section_1_cell"]autorelease];

    }

    cell.textLabel.text= [jointWrkNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:17.f];
}

//Detailing
if(indexPath.section == 2)
{
    cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"section_2_cell"];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell= [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"section_2_cell"]autorelease];

    }

    cell.textLabel.text= @"Detailing";
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:17.f];
}
return cell;
}
```

For the successful reusing if the correct cell, the `cellIdentifier` must be unique for different types of cells. Hence a different identifier for each section.

Comment: thanx buddy, your method worked like charm. Just changing the 'CellIdentifier' did the trick. Thanx again.

Comment: Where you reuse cell in table view ?

Comment: i didnt get you. Could u rephrase your question?

Answer (score 0):

Well you simply have to **remove the instances** of the `UILabel's` in each cell of the `UITableView` before each reload of the `UITableView`. This would help you

After you create your cell like

```
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Identifier";        
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];        
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:nil];
    }
```

Add this

```
 for(id obj in cell.contentView.subviews)
    {
        if([obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            [obj removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
```

Hope your issue is cleared now !

Comment: removing and adding UIlabel seems complicated. I think changing identifier looks simple.

Comment: Well you'll think its simple now but u havnt' started facing the issues yet... :D ... Also it is more lengthy ... say you have more than 10 sections and you think you'll add 10 more lines of code for each section ?? Think about it...

Answer (score 0):

Make the allocation of label if the cell is created ie when the cell is nil

```
if(cell==nil)
    {
           cell= [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"]autorelease];
           UILabel *name = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    }
```

Comment: Not enough to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to reuse cell in Table View

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"section_0_cell"];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"section_0_cell"];
        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:17.f];
        UILabel *name = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        name.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        name.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        name.frame = CGRectMake(600,2.0f,250,50);

        [cell addSubview:name];
        name.tag=100;
    }

    UILabel *name = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    name.hidden=YES;
    //Doc Name
    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        name.hidden=NO;
        cell.textLabel.text= docName;
        name.text = @"11:12:01";
    }

    //Joint Work
    if(indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text= [jointWrkNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    //Detailing
    if(indexPath.section == 2)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text= @"Detailing";
    }
    return cell;
}
```